# wso2 esb connector how to share accesstoken in cluster environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am working on a project by using wso2 esb as integration bus, and esb is running on cluster environment. Now ESB will connect to third party application (like salesforce) via connector, and salesforce will issue accesstoken to esb connector. There are two issues here:

## 1 how to refresh access token periodically

the accesstoken will be expired every 2 hours, so how to avoid a request is invalid by expired accesstoken (in general, system needs to get a new token every 2 hours). I didn't see this configuration in ESB sample.

## 2 how to share access token in cluster environment

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 Salesforce REST connector is released in [store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/fbb433b5-4d74-4064-84c2-e4b23c531aa2) with supporting token refreshing and it will support to share access token in cluster environment.

```
<salesforcerest.init>
    <accessToken>{$ctx:accessToken}</accessToken>
    <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
    <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
    <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
    <refreshToken>{$ctx:refreshToken}</refreshToken>
    <hostName>{$ctx:hostName}</hostName>
    <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
    <registryPath>{$ctx:registryPath}</registryPath>
    <intervalTime>{$ctx:intervalTime}</intervalTime>
 <salesforcerest.init>
```

In above configuration, intervalTime is in milliseconds to check the access token validity. For example, Salesforce access token is expired in 2 hours. So you need to give the intervalTime in milliseconds less than 2 hours. Once the token is expired, when you call the connector method, it will check the access token validity. If it is expired, the connector will refresh the access token using refresh token and save it in registry. In above configuration, you can give the registry path. if you don't pass registry path in the configuration, the connector will save the access token in default registry path.

In WSO2 ESB deployments config registry is usually mounted and shared among cluster nodes so you can share access token in cluster environment

You can refer the wso2 [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Salesforce+REST+Connector) and the [blog](http://mrmalakasilva.blogspot.com/2016/06/seamless-token-refresh-in-your.html) for the connector configuration. The Connector zip file can be downloaded from [here](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/fbb433b5-4d74-4064-84c2-e4b23c531aa2). Go to the link and click the 'download connector' button and follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Salesforce+REST+Connector) for the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In above configuration you must give the registry path as "connectors/"connectorname"". If you are like to get the accessToken from username password flow you don't need to worry about the accessToken expiration(Only for Salesforce REST connector). You can follow [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Salesforce+Operations#ConfiguringSalesforceOperations-initwithusernamepasswordflow) about username password flow. In other cases like Google API connectors(Example Gmail) you don't need to give the registry path because the connector itself create a registry location to store the accessToken.